# Finding value of theta in linear classification

Tags: classification, logistic-regression

I have an examing coming up, and I'm practicing with exams from previous years. However, the answers to the questions are not provided unfortunately.

I'm currently doing the question below, and the intuitive answer I get is 2. However, this seems too easy. Am I correct?

[image: Question]

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an exam question, I will give you hints and leading questions instead of answers.

Note that $x^T w$ must be well-defined, and $x$ is 2-dimensional. What is the dimension of $w$?

How is bias incorporated into the model?

The margin satisfies $\widehat{y} = 0.$ What is the equation of the margin (as a function of x and bias)?

P.S. I expect a typo/vagueness in this question.

Comment: The dimension of  are also 2-dimensional, no?  = [2, 2]

Comment: Let's give it a shot. The margin line passes through $x = (1, 4).$ For this $x$, $x^T w$ is "indecisive", and, therefore, it should be zero. Does your answer fit?

Comment: After going through the lecture slides, I finally ended up with 1 = 1 and 2 = -(1/3). Is this correct?

Comment: The equation of the line is $-2-2x_1 + x_2=0.$ First, I make sure that positives are above the line and negatives are below the line. Secondly, we need to choose the appropriate scaling, e.g., $-4-4x_1+2x_2=0$ would be the equation for the same line but would lead to a different $w$. I use the margins for that. And I got a different answer.

Comment: However, my margin line has a bias, and in the example, there is no bias. I am very confused about it.

Comment: Just verifying, the line $1\cdot x_1 -1/3 x_2 = 0$ can also be used as a separation line, but it is different from the one on the picture. Also, the signs are flipped. $w_1=-1$ and $w_2=1/3$ may do as weights in the model without bias.